# Using jest spyOn cannot detect methods being called inside try-catch block

Tags: jestjs, spy

The problem I'm having is that Jest is reporting setResultsSpy is being called 0 times when in fact, I know that it is being called. I know this by putting `console.log(results)` under the `const results = await getFileList(data.path);` in my code and was able to see results returned.

My guess right now is that try-catch blocks creates a local scope, which is causing those calls to not be registered. If this is true, my question is "how can I test if those methods have been called"?

```
// test_myFunction.js

test((`myFunction with valid path should return list of files`), () => {
  const actions = {
    setMsg: () => { },
    setButton: () => {},
    setResults: () => {},
    setAppState: () => {}
  };
  const setMsgSpy = jest.spyOn(actions, 'setMsg');
  const setSubmitButtonStateSpy = jest.spyOn(actions, 'setButton');
  const setResultsSpy = jest.spyOn(actions, 'setResults');
  const setAppStateSpy = jest.spyOn(actions, 'setAppState');
  const returnedFileList = [
    'file1.pdf',
    'file2.pdf',
    'file3.pdf',
  ];
  const requestConfig = {
    component: COMPONENTS.myComponent,
    request: RequestTypes.REQUEST,
    data: {path: 'folder1'},
    actions
  };

  processRequest(requestConfig)

  expect(setMsgSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(setMsgSpy)
  .toHaveBeenCalledWith('loading');

  expect(setButtonSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

  expect(setResultsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(setResultsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(returnedFileList);

  expect(setAppStateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(setAppStateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('confirm');
});
```

_

```
// myFunction.js
async function processRequest({
  component,
  request,
  data,
  actions,
}){
  if (component === COMPONENTS.myComponent) {
    const path = data.path.trim();
    switch (request) {
      case RequestTypes.REQUEST:
        actions.setMsg('message');
        actions.setButton('disabled');

          try {
            const results = await getFileList(data.path);
            actions.setResults(results);
            actions.setAppState('confirm');
          } catch (e) {
            actions.setError(e);
            actions.setAppState('error');
          }
        }
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The the problem was Jest was failing out of the test before the results from `getFileList()` execution has completed since getFileList() is an async function.

The solution is for the test to handle the execution asynchronously [as per the documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous). There are 4 ways to solve this problem:

1. Use callbacks
2. Use `.then()` and `.catch()` on the returned promise (see docs on `.then()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) and `.catch()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch))
3. Use `.resolves()` or `.rejects()` Jest methods on `expect()` to let Jest resolve the promise.
4. Use Async-Await syntax by declaring the test anonymous function as `async` and using `await` on `processRequest()` .

I went with option 4 as I enjoy using async-await syntax. Here's the solution:

```
// test_myFunction.js

test((`myFunction with valid path should return list of files`), async () => {
  //(all of the variables established from above)    

  await processRequest(requestConfig)

  expect(setMsgSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(setMsgSpy)
  .toHaveBeenCalledWith('loading');

  expect(setButtonSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

  expect(setResultsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(setResultsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(returnedFileList);

  expect(setAppStateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(setAppStateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('confirm');
});
```

Notice `async` being used on the first line and `await` when calling `processRequest(requestConfig)`.